# Creating pdf or eps image file from inkscape with the same fonts in the images as in the main file?

Tags: inkscape, latex

I was trying to upload my files to the editorial manager system of a journal, but it does not support *.pdf_tex files which I created using inkscape for my figures. Now, I need to convert those images into pdf/eps with the same font (size, style etc) as that in my original document. How to do that?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Hey Ayan! What are you having trouble with exactly? Does Inkscape not allow exporting to pdf/eps?

Comment: The journal which I am submitting my papers to has an inbuilt tex management system. But their system does not support *.pdf_tex formats which I created while I made the figures originally (on my computer, they are working fine). I want to ask how to convert those figure files now into pdf, not distorting the fonts inside it.

Answer (score 1):

On exporting to PDF Inkscape allows converting text to paths. In the PDF-Save dialog tick

- *Convert texts to paths*

To also keep filters we may have applied tick

- *Rasterize filter effects*

[image]

This will keep all text with the original font and font attributes but text will only be editable as a path on re-importing and objects with filter effects will have been converted to non-vector bitmaps.

Comment: I would like to add to @Takkat reply, that you can rename the file ".pdf_tex" to just simply ".tex", since it is just a text file.
Assuming your submission system allows LaTeX files. Regards,